# Listview vs TableView in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, listview, tableview

I need to recreate this table in my app: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FD7Mj.jpg
The third field must be editable by the user, so I don't know if I should prefer ListView for this reason. What do you think?
Also, do you know if are there existing library to create this exactly design?

Comment: add some code what you have tried so far\

Comment: `What do you think?` this is wrong place to ask for opinions. In fact you can use both - ListVIew, or TableLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends whether your table holds data that will change or you will always have the same table with editable third field. If you have static data you don't really need to have a list.
If you have data that changes, RecyclerView is your go to option. Create it with different ViewHolder types, one type for non-editable fields and the other for editable field.
Also, there is no need to add 3rd party library just to achieve this simple table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recyclerview with different views Like [this](https://medium.com/@droidbyme/android-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type-multiple-view-holder-af798458763b) and [this](https://trinitytuts.com/recyclerview-with-multiple-views-using-custom-adapter-in-android/)